# How to handle database exceptions using Telerik ORM

Tags: c#, orm, telerik

I'm using Visual Studio with a Telerik OpenAccess ORM. Right now I have code that checks the database (via ORM) to see if a user exists upon login. I'm currently testing for non existent users, but doing so throws an exception. I want to wrap the request in a try-catch block in order to keep my program from crashing.

```
 public ActionResult Login(string password)
    {
        var db = ContextFactory.GetContextPerRequest();
        var username = Request.Form["username"].ToString();

        // try-catch (This line crashes the program)
        var user = (from u in db.Users where u.Username == username select u).Single();
        // end try-catch

        ViewBag.Login = new bool?(false);
        if (user.UserId != null)
        {
            ViewBag.Login = new bool?(true);
        }

        return View("Index");
    }
```

I'd appreciate any assistance given.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: @Matthew It gives me `Telerik.OpenAccess.OpenAccessException`. Here's an image with more info: http://i.imgur.com/WGNNl9H.png